# Inserting Biometrics in sql varbinary

Tags: sql, vb6, varbinary, biometrics

I want to insert the value of `obj.BIR` in a field with data type `varbinary`

I'm getting this error:

> "The multi-part identifier "obj.BIR could not be bound"

This is my code:

```
strSQLStmt = "INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[BioData] ([BIO]) VALUES (CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5',"
strSQLStmt = strSQLStmt + " obj.BIR "
strSQLStmt = strSQLStmt + ") as BINARY(16)))"
```

Comment: What is `obj.BIR`? Is it a variable in your VB code?

Comment: Obj.bir is the biometric data captured into a template : Template(index)=obj.Bir

Answer (score 0):

do you really have to save your biometrics into a column of data type varbinary? Why dont you change it to blob?